# accessing class property which is added by frord declaration from another class

Tags: ios

I have a class

```
@interface AppRecord : NSObject

  @property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * urlSingle;
  @property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray * image_url;

@end
```

It is included in another class

```
@class AppRecord;
@interface IconDownloader : NSObject

  @property (nonatomic, strong) AppRecord *appRecord;

@end
```

This is my root view controller

```
#import "IconDownloader.h"
@implementation RootViewController
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.imageDownloadsInProgress = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
}

- (void)startIconDownload:(AppRecord *)appRecord forIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
        IconDownloader *iconDownloader = [self.imageDownloadsInProgress objectForKey:indexPath];
if (iconDownloader == nil)
{
   iconDownloader = [[IconDownloader alloc] init];         
    int imgArrCount=[appRecord.image_url count];
    NSLog(@"Image array is********************** %@",appRecord.image_url);
    for(int i=0;i<imgArrCount;i++)
    {
        iconDownloader.appRecord.urlSingle=[appRecord.image_url objectAtIndex:i];
        NSLog(@"iconDownloader.appRecord.urlSingle---------------------%@",iconDownloader.appRecord.urlSingle);


    }
 }  
}   

@end
```

Can i assign iconDownloader.appRecord.urlSingle here, I am having null value.Please help.

Comment: Sorry, but your question is not clear to me

Comment: You can do `#import AppRecord.h`. Or is there anu specific reason why you are using `@class`?

Comment: I got this from apple document thts why

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has nothing to do with forward declaration. When you forward declare a class, you should `#import` the `.h` file before using any of the class properties/methods.

The problem is property `appRecord` in `iconDownloader` is not created yet and hence is `nil`. In your code you should do this.

```
- (void)startIconDownload:(AppRecord *)appRecord forIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

    //...

    for(int i=0;i<imgArrCount;i++)
    {
        // First assign to the property so that it is not nil
        iconDownloader.appRecord = appRecord;
        // If required then make this assignment
        iconDownloader.appRecord.urlSingle=[appRecord.image_url objectAtIndex:i];
    }

    //...
}
```

Alternately, you can also override the `init` in `IconDownloader` class and create the `appRecord` property inside it, so that it is not `nil` when you are assigning values.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

You didnt initializing the *appRecord* object. thats why you get null value. Just initialize *appRecord* in your *init* method like:

```
-(id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {

        appRecord = [[AppRecord alloc]init];
    }
    return self;
}
```

Similiarly you have to initialize the *urlSingle* variable inside the init definition:

```
-(id)init
    {
        self = [super init];
        if (self) {

            urlSingle = URL_STRING_HERE;
        }
        return self;
    }
```

Now you try